# Find average minimum and select all values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with company, products, region and price

```
Company | Product | Region | Price
ABC          ROO      1       10
ABC          BAR      1       12 
ABC          BAR      2       12
DEF          DOO      1       11
DEF          BAR      2       8 
etc....
```

There are multiple different products linked to the company

I have the following code to find the cheapest product per region for each company and pivot it

```
WITH tableFix
 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company, T.Region ORDER BY T.Price) AS RegionalPosition 

FROM dbo.MainTablePlus AS T
) AS B   
WHERE B.SupplierRegionalTariffPosition =1 -- Filters applied here - is currently set to retrieve top 1 tariffs per region
)
SELECT Company ,Product, [Region 1],[Region 2],[Region 3],[Region 4],[Region 4] 
FROM 
(
SELECT Company, Product, Region, Price
FROM tableFix) UP
PIVOT (MIN(Price) FOR Region IN ([Region 1],[Region 2],[Region 3],[Region 4],[Region 4] )) AS pvt
ORDER BY Company, Product
```

However when I run this it picks up more than one product per company when there is a cheaper product in one region like so:

```
Company | Product | Region 1 | Region 2 | Region 3.....
 ABC        ROO        NA         12        10
 ABC        FAR        6          NA        NA
 DEF        BAR        9          8         7
 GHI        FOO        8          6         9
```

It picks two products for company ABC but I want it to pick the cheapest overall like so

```
Company | Product | Region 1 | Region 2 ...... Region 10
 ABC        ROO        10         12
 DEF        BAR        9          8
 GHI        FOO        8          6
```

I am doing this on Microsoft SQL server management studio

Comment: How do you decide which product to choose when different products can be cheapest in different regions for the same company?

Comment: I want the cheapest product overall, and then show that product for all regions

Comment: Define the cheapest product overall. To me sound like should be only one, but your sample show many products. Is cheapest product by company or by region or combination of both. Explain the logic and we can help.

Comment: Company ABC has two different regions. You are including region in your partition by clause, so you're going to get two rows for company ABC coming out of your CTE.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza there are many products for one company, but I want to select the product that is the cheapest overall for as many regions there are.

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select company,
       min(case when region = 'Region 1' then price end) as region_1,
       min(case when region = 'Region 2' then price end) as region_2,
       min(case when region = 'Region 3' then price end) as region_3,
       . . .
from (select mtp.*,
             min(seqnum) over (partition by company, product) as product_price_seqnum
      from (select mtp.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by company order by price) as price_seqnum
            from MainTablePlus mtp
           ) mtp
     ) mtp
where product_price_seqnum = 1
group by company;
```

The two levels of subqueries assign the value "1" to the product that has the minimum price.  If there are ties, then one is arbitrarily chosen.